# Is there a memcached memory limit best practice?

Tags: memcached, best-practices, memcache

Is there a best practice or general rule of thumb when setting the memory limit for memcached?

I'm currently running memcached with the default memory limit of 64 megabytes. The server has 8 gigabytes of memory installed out of which only around 512 megabytes of memory are available.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8g and .5 available sounds fishy.  If nothing else significant is running then you should be able to run at 6-7G pretty easily.  I suspect you are looking at 'free' memory which doesn't account for linux disk caching and such.

Comment: Thanks. I found that MySQL was using 7GB unnecessarily. I reduced memory used by MySQL to 3GB, and I doubled memcache memory usage from 64MB to 128MB.